# P-value adjustment in correlational analysis

Tags: correlation, p-value

I'm currently doing some large correlational analysis: Let's just say I wanted every kendall-correlation and it's associated p-value from 20x30 Items in a neat matrix - should I be doing p-value adjustment correcting for multiple comparisons, eg. holm (nothing's significant) or should I just use the passthrough option adjustment="none" (lots of significance) and be done with it?

Sample Size is 145-153 depending on pairwise deletion, Korrelations are quite low(-.14/+28), using R with corr.test from psych-package

Goal is exploring possible associative relationships between items

Thanks in advance!

JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a lot of correlations and I assume you have a reasonably large sample size. Post-hoc correction for statistical significance is a pretty crude method for adjusting for multiple comparisons. Even using post-hoc corrections:

- you aren't guaranteed that the findings that show as statistically significant are only those that "truly are"
- the post-hoc correction may mean that some "truly" significant correlations will be bumped down to statistical insignificance.
  Basically, with a large number of statistical tests, you'll get quite a few statistically significant by chance, and the post hoc correction isn't a guaranteed fix.

Do you have a theory about why some items might correlate? What about multidimensional associations? Why are you looking at so many 2-way tests?

Update: is there some reason why you're not using principal components analysis or structural equation modelling? Either of these seems suited to your analysis *assuming you wish to identify associations between variables and not between people*.

Comment: well there is not really a theory, but some literature and most research projects assume a direct relationship between certain used methods and an latent variable in organizations. because the scale we constructed did not quite work out we attemp to correlate the items directly.

Comment: I like @Michelle's comments, and since one of your goals is scale development, I'd definitely look into factor analysis--or principal component analysis if you have error-free items.  If you search for "Spector" you'll find a reference to a nice, inexpensive little book on using F.A. and reliability analysis for scale development.  Just because the method you tried didn't give good results doesn't mean there aren't workable scales latent in your data.  But trying to analyze a 20 x 30 corr. matrix sounds grim indeed.

Comment: CFA rejected our original model with RMSEA of .10 and i've already been through fa which tells me that there are more factors than expected, high crossloadings on some items and inferred items do not make much sense

Comment: The sample size seems a bit low for all these methods (confirmatory or exploratory factor analysis), especially with such low correlations. Not that I have a better idea, though…